# kdump is not collecting the core file during the system panic

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was going through the doc https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-kdump-configuration-cli.html on configuring the coredump collector.

I have made the following to changes and have restarted the kdump with the command "service kdump restart".

On /etc/kdump.conf => I have enabled the path and the core-collector as below,

```
path /var/crash
core_collector makedumpfile -c
#default halt
```

And on /boot/grub/grub.conf

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.18-318.6.1.el5.20)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-318.6.1.el5.20 ro root=/dev/Raid_vg/Root_lv  crashkernel=256M@16M
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-318.6.1.el5.20.img
title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.18-110.el5)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-110.el5 ro root=/dev/Raid_vg/Root_lv  crashkernel=256M@16M
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-110.el5.img
```

I did the above to trigger the crash dump "cho c > /proc/sysrq-trigger". But after the reboot the core files are not present in the /var/crash.

Please help to identify why the core dump was not generated.

I see the config file of the kernel with the following enabled,

CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP=y but CONFIG_RELOCATABLE is not present in the config. Is it becoz of that the core dump didnt get generated.

Comment: Looks like you are on RHEL5. What is the error message you get when you run `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger` command. Do you see any messages in the `/var/log/messages/` or on the console ?

Comment: Also have you tried the kdumphelper script provided by the vendor on the portal ?

Comment: I saw it on the remote console.. But no core dump was getting created.

Comment: Check the message you get in syslog as mention d earlier, if require more help.